# Can we increase Torrent share ratio using Local Peer Discovery?

Tags: bittorrent, peer-to-peer

I just want to know whether this is a flaw or not in Bittorrent system.

Let us assume that I am member of a Private Torrent site which requires me to maintain a specific upload to download ratio.

Will this work:

- I create a torrent of a large file say [ Fedora Linux ~ 4 GB ] and upload it to the tracker
- I download the same torrent using my ID and start it on another machine on LAN or a Virtual machine
- Both clients have Local Peer Discovery enabled, so they will find 'em [ not via DHT ] and start x'ferring data using LAN bandwidth at LAN speeds.
- Though both uploads and downloads will increase, my ratio will also increase
- If I reiterate the entire process 'n' times, the numerator in the "RATIO" i.e Upload will become so large that the effect of downloads on ratio will become less.

I want to know whether this is legitimate???

**Update**: This does work. :-)

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are programs that can spoof your download/upload ratios anyway, so I would say this point is pretty much moot.

Comment: Trackers look at IP activity (when submitting your upload/download stats to the site) and probably flag that sort of thing; you will get banned.

Answer (score 3):

I would assume that the developers of bittorrent clients supporting local peer discovery would have already thought of this situation and not include upload/download statistics from local peers in the statistics reported to the tracker.

Or the client may not allow local peer discovery on torrents that are marked as private, similar to how DHT is disabled on private torrents.

If a client didn't behave in one of these two ways it would likely be blacklisted from most private trackers.

Additionally private trackers warn when using a seedbox not to download from your own seedbox using another client using the same account because it effects their statistics and would cause you to be labeled as reporting incorrect upload/download amounts, resulting in your account being banned. This is a similar situation to the one you described because both involve using the same account.

Answer (score 1):

Just creating and seeding your own torrent(s) will bring your share ratio up, I don't think you understand what seeding your own torrent means. You don't download your own torrent. That being said you need to seed something others want to get large positive ratio numbers.

You do not upload the actual file to the tracker site, only the very small torrent file you create, you will host the actual 4gb file on your PC and seed it to others that download your torrent file because they want what you have.

No need to scam the system, you will get banned eventually.

How to create a torrent
http://torrentfreak.com/how-to-create-a-torrent/

.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, private torrent sites will automatically disable [DHT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_hash_table), [LPD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Peer_Discovery), and [PEX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peer_exchange) on torrents. This flag cannot be removed without changing the hash of the torrent, which would likely not match, which would not only cause peers to no longer share with you, but would also not synchronize with the torrent tracker (torrent not known).

If such flag is not set, you will still be flagged by the tracker and be investigated by the admins. If they find that you have been "cheating" in such a way, they will likely remove your account.